# PostgreSQL case insensitive SELECT on array

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, case-insensitive

I'm having problems finding the answer here, on google or in the docs ...
I need to do a case insensitive select against an array type.

So if:

```
value = {"Foo","bar","bAz"}
```

I need

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE 'foo' = ANY(value)
```

to match.

I've tried lots of combinations of lower() with no success.

`ILIKE` instead of `=` seems to work but I've always been nervous about `LIKE` - is that the best way?

Comment: So ILIKE is ruled out as pointed out by @Chris Travers below - it's quite likely that a value could legitimately contain an underscore

Comment: So it wasn't such a dumb question then @Erwin? :) (first time I've been edited - not complaining, just fascinated)

Comment: On the contrary: it's a very interesting question, IMO, and it has attracted a number of interesting answers already. But primarily I edited that bit out, because we try to keep the noise ratio in questions and answers low on SO. Some noise can go into comments. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One alternative not mentioned is to install [the `citext` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html) that comes with PostgreSQL 8.4+ and use an array of `citext`:

```
regress=# CREATE EXTENSION citext;
regress=# SELECT 'foo' = ANY( '{"Foo","bar","bAz"}'::citext[] );
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

If you want to be strictly correct about this and avoid extensions you have to do some [pretty ugly subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/398670) because Pg doesn't have many rich array operations, in particular no functional mapping operations. Something like:

```
SELECT array_agg(lower(($1)[n])) FROM generate_subscripts($1,1) n;
```

... where $1 is the array parameter. In your case I think you can cheat a bit because you don't care about preserving the array's order, so you can do something like:

```
SELECT 'foo' IN (SELECT lower(x) FROM unnest('{"Foo","bar","bAz"}'::text[]) x);
```

Comment: +1 on citext. May or may not be practical for the OP, but it's the perfect opportunity to mention that extension.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter is right - I can't install libraries sadly - it's a bit of a black-box instance

Comment: Actually, you can wrap the subquery in a function (I just added this to my answer) so that lower(array_of_text) will just work.

Answer (score 22):

This seems hackish to me but I think it should work

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE 'foo' = ANY(lower(value::text)::text[])
```

`ilike` could have issues if your arrays can have `_` or `%`

Note that what you are doing is converting the text array to a single text string, converting it to lower case, and then back to an array.  This should be safe.  If this is not sufficient you could use various combinations of string_to_array and array_to_string, but I think the standard textual representations should be safer.

**Update** building on subquery solution below, one option would be a simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lower(text[]) RETURNS text[] LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
$$
SELECT array_agg(lower(value)) FROM unnest($1) value;
$$;
```

Then you could do:

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE 'foo' = ANY(lower(value));
```

This might actually be the best approach.  You could also create GIN indexes on the output of the function if you want.

Comment: Useful hack. I don't *think* there are any charsets/locales where `lower` will transform chars that the array syntax cares about. (BTW, I sometimes wish Pg had array `map`, `filter` and `fold`/`foldl`/`foldr` for those cases where PL/PgSQL is overkill but pure SQL is clumsy. Array `sort` too, actually.)

Comment: @craig, agree.  Actually sort could be easily done with a plain sql function.

Comment: Actually, maybe it would be worth putting together an extension with these array functions.  They could all be sql or pl/pgsql easily enough.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Easily, but not necessarily *efficiently*. Array access at SQL level isn't super-efficient unfortunately. One day I'll get around to writing them, array access in C doesn't look too hard and things like sorts can be done with generic opclass actions.

Comment: @ChrisTraversI actually tried your function but it returns NULL for empty array, I posted another answer that uses casting to text instead.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative would be with `unnest()`

```
WITH tbl AS (SELECT 1 AS id, '{"Foo","bar","bAz"}'::text[] AS value)

SELECT value
FROM  (SELECT id, value, unnest(value) AS val FROM tbl) x
WHERE  lower(val) = 'foo'
GROUP  BY id, value;
```

I added an `id` column to get *exactly* identical results - i.e. duplicate `value` if there are duplicates in the base table. Depending on your circumstances, you can probably omit the `id` from the query to collapse duplicates in the results or if there are no dupes to begin with. Also demonstrating a syntax alternative:

```
SELECT value
FROM  (SELECT value, lower(unnest(value)) AS val FROM tbl) x
WHERE  val = 'foo'
GROUP  BY value;
```

If array elements are unique within arrays in lower case, you don't even need the `GROUP BY`, since every `value` can only match once.

```
SELECT value
FROM  (SELECT value, lower(unnest(value)) AS val FROM tbl) x
WHERE  val = 'foo';
```

`'foo'` must be lower case, obviously.
Should be *fast*.

If you want that *fast* wit a big table, I would create a *functional GIN index*, though.

Comment: Also note you can take the subquery and write a lower(text[]) function so it just works.

Comment: While that works and simplifies the code, it would be slower. You would go back and forth between array and set representation. You could base the functional GIN Index I mentioned on it, though. Then you have fast & simple syntax.

Answer (score 0):

my solution to exclude values using a sub select...

```
and groupname not ilike all (
    select unnest(array[exceptionname||'%'])
    from public.group_exceptions
    where ...
      and ...
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression may do the job for most cases

SELECT array_to_string('{"a","b","c"}'::text[],'|') ~* ANY('{"A","B","C"}');

Answer (score 0):

I find creating a custom PostgreSQL function works best for me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lower(text_array text[]) RETURNS text[] AS
    $BODY$
         SELECT (lower(text_array::text))::text[] 
    $BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```