# SELECT with case sensitive ANY

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with column of arrays that contains words in different cases. I can select all rows with required tag like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'tag' = ANY(tags::TEXT[]);
```

but how to take into account that words in arrays can also be in upper case?

---

UPDATE

that's how can I get all unique values from column of arrays:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(unnest)
        FROM (SELECT unnest(tags) FROM table) AS all_tags;
```

maybe it will be helpful

Comment: How do you want to "take them into account"? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @lurker I'm looking for 'tag' but cannot find any of {'Tag', 'TAG', 'tAg' }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL case insensitive SELECT on array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311289/postgresql-case-insensitive-select-on-array)

Comment: @Demo working, but looking only opposite values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from my_table
where 'tag' ilike any(tags)
```

[Per the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale.

Comment: I don't understand. Try it here: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7d51f/1) and show what doesn't work (paste the link of the modified example).

Comment: doesn't work if upper and lower cases contains in one array

Comment: What do you mean - doesn't work? See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48f71/1)

Answer (score 0):

this query finds all

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, lower(unnest(tags)) AS val FROM table) x WHERE val = 'c++';
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a choice and choose to set tag field to be upper case or not, and the content of your array also in the same state. 
For this you  can save the tag, or update your actual content to upper or lower case and define an index on this field and then set the array content to the same state.